API Redcap : file repository using Stata
I'm using Stata to get files that are in file repository in redcap but i can't do it.
I have two files in the folder "test" in my file repository and i want to import them.
I am trying this :
shell  `curlpath'   ///
    --form token=`apitoken' ///
    --form content=fileRepository   ///
    --form action=list      ///
    --form format=csv       ///
    --form folder_id=4      ///
    --form returnFormat=csv         ///
    `apiurl'

but it doesn't work, do you know why?
Thanks !

I don't think anyone can answer this if you don't explain what is in your local macro curlpath or what "doesn't work" means.

Ditto apitoken.

Sorry, i worked with https://github.com/lsgs/REDCap-API-and-Stata
Curlpath is my curl path (C:/Windows/System32/curl.exe)
And it does nothing when i run this

That's more information; thanks. Someone may be better placed to give an answer.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You have a couple of things going on here that you'll need to change.
First, you're using the list action, which is going to return a csv string (because you've used format=csv) of files in the folder.  That will actually be a little useful, because it will give you the document IDs you need to actually get your files.
To get your files, you need to use action=export and then you'll need to replace folder_id with doc_id and use the document ID of the file you want to pull out of the repository.
The API method only pulls one file at a time, so you will need to make a separate call for each file.
shell  `curlpath'   ///
    --form token=`apitoken' ///
    --form content=fileRepository   ///
    --form action=export      ///
    --form doc_id=[1234]      ///
    --form returnFormat=csv         ///
    `apiurl'

